# df reports disk usage but no files in shared memory /dev/shm

Tags: c++, linux, posix, shared-memory

I'm trying to program using shared memory/c++.  I have multiple processes accessing a shared memory piece, which then unlinks during the execution and links to another piece once it's done with the previous piece.

All works, except, when i list ls /dev/shm it is empty, but when i df /dev/shm it says space consumed, why is it?

Comment: You should check what df command really do. man df - http://linux.die.net/man/1/df  and man ls - http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls

Comment: I tried ls and ll, there really doesn't seem to be anything.

Comment: If one of the answer helped you. please consider to accept it, see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `shm_unlik()`, keep in mind that `shm_unlik`:

> "remove the name of the shared memory object named by the string
>   pointed to by name."

**but**

> "the removal of the memory object contents shall be postponed until
>   all open and map references to the shared memory object have been
>   removed."

(as stated in the man [page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/shm_unlink.html))

Thus it is possible that you don't see anything with `ls` but you still see the memory as occupied by using `df`.

Comment: Old question, same problem though.  How short of a full reboot can you find and remove the process that is using the shared memory?